# CTE query Not returning any result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

The following query works

```
select TOP 100 T.DWH_ID,T.date_time, T.TimeDiff, T.[End Date], T.SPS_Bereich, T.txtName from (  
SELECT sto.[DWH_ID]
      ,sto.[SPS_Bereich]
      ,FORMAT(sto.[DateTime], 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm') as date_time
      ,sto.[txtName]
      ,sto.[TimeDiff]
      , DATEADD(second,sto.[TimeDiff],FORMAT(sto.[DateTime], 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm'))as [End Date]
  FROM [Stoerdaten].[sta].[Stoerungen]  sto where sto.Classname='Alarm' and sto.TimeDiff>60 ) as T

  join  [IgnitionServer].[dbo].[scheduled_events_ISTProduction] cal on 

  ((T.date_time between cal.start_date and cal.end_date) and T.[End Date] between cal.start_date and cal.end_date) where cal.typ=1 order by [DWH_ID] desc
```

But when I change to CTE it didn't give me any result.

CTE Query

```
;with q1 as 
  (
  select TOP 1000 [DWH_ID], 
  SPS_Bereich ,
  FORMAT([DateTime], 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm') as date_time,
   [txtName],
    [TimeDiff]
    , DATEADD(second,[TimeDiff],FORMAT([DateTime], 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm'))as [End_Date]
  FROM [Stoerdaten].[sta].[Stoerungen] where Classname='Alarm' and TimeDiff>60 
  )

  select q1.DWH_ID,
  q1.date_time, 
  q1.TimeDiff, q1.[End_Date], q1.txtName, q1.SPS_Bereich   from  q1 join [IgnitionServer].[dbo].[scheduled_events_ISTProduction] cal on 
  ((q1.date_time between cal.start_date and cal.end_date) and q1.[End_Date] between cal.start_date and cal.end_date)  where cal.typ=1
```

I don't understand what I am missing here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: your query not showing the result becuase the first one without cte is fetching top 1000 after joining two tables, whereas your cte is first fetching top 1000 and then joining with other tables. Those 1000 rows are not fulling the criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CTE contains the TOP 1000 records in `[sta].[Stoerungen]` with the `WHERE` criteria and you then join from that to `[scheduled_events_ISTProduction]`.

In your initial query, you're returning the TOP 100 *after* the JOIN has been made, so I imagine that whatever is appearing in the result of your CTE can't be joined to the records in `[scheduled_events_ISTProduction]`.

If you just select everything out of your CTE you should see that there are up to 1000 records in there but should also be able to verify the JOIN issue.

Comment: the first retruns 100 rows with join but in CTE i have used 1000 so it has to returns me something.

Comment: @Tarun.P - Remove the 'top 1000' from your CTE and see what you get back.

Comment: `order by [DWH_ID] desc` is used in first query. Yes you are correct there is no data. thanks all